# .js.erb Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

- I have a controller named : 
  listing_controller.erb

  ```
   def show
     @base_url = request.env['HTTP_HOST']
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render :action => "show.js.erb" }
       format.html { render :action => "show.html.haml"}
     end
   end
  ```
- and I have a file having type **js.erb** named 
  **show.js.erb**

  ```
   alert("Hello");
  ```
- when I run action show Why file show.js.erb does not work?

Comment: do you have routes to that show action? e.g.: match '/foo' => 'controller-name#show'

Comment: No controller has .erb extension... is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

1. Rails is easy, however, not so easy that you can start writing code without reading any documents. 
   you should re-study the official tutorial : http://guides.rubyonrails.org.
2. your code is not correct at all. delete it , then read the official tutorial again. or use the code generated by scaffold.
3. when you want to render the js file, use

   http://localhost:xx/some_action.js

so that Rails knows you are requesting the js resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a layout in the controller like

```
layout "foo/bar"
```

you must render without a layout in your action:

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.js{ render layout: false }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe format.js refers to what happens when you specify the format parameter via get request not what files to include.

You shouldn't use your erb stuff for js files unless you are outputting json. You should only be formatting content there.

Instead you should either including js files in "app/assets/javascripts" or 'vendor/assets/javascripts' then you need to make sure to include your files as normal via script tags. Like: `= javascript_include_tag "map"`

Then when rails does all that cool precompile stuff it will collapse everything in your assets folder and vendor folders into one file. You can specify a different location if you'd like as well. Rails figures out where the file is by searching for it. I believe app/assets/ is looked at first.

Comment: This answer is nonsense. It's perfectly fine to return Javascript like this. E.g. you can use it for hiding, showing or appending content after an Ajax request.

Comment: @Mischa I was just saying that there is no point in doing so unless you have dynamic content. Why on earth would you bind yourself to serving js files in this way if you can just serve it as a static asset? I clearly said unless you are trying to serve JSON.

Comment: I saw your remark about JSON, but you can also return "normal" Javascript via a .js.erb file. Your answer assumes the asker wants to use his .js.erb view instead of assets, but there is nothing in the question that suggests that.

Comment: @Mischa I didn't say it wasn't possible to do. I gave an easier approach that would decouple the logic. It seemed like he was attempting to have the alert popup run on page load, which is just static content anyways. It also seemed like he was trying to include his javascript file via the controller. I said that format parameter is used to select which file to render.

This way it forces the asker to include js via the script tag, and not assume that some magic is being done.

Comment: No, you didn't say it wasn't impossible, but you said *you shouldn't do it*. That's the main reason I don't like your answer. You mention the `alert`, but probably `alert("Hello")` isn't the real functionality he was trying to build. Anyway, the question is almost a year old and I guess we can agree to disagree.

Comment: By the way, [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) you can see how index.js.erb is used to add content to a div after an Ajax call. Seems to me this is perfectly valid use of Javascript and it doesn't have anything to do with JSON or formatting content.